# Identify view being touched

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a layout that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_read_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.project.books.flipview.FlipView
        android:id="@+id/flip_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_black"
        app:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".ReadActivity" >
    </com.project.books.flipview.FlipView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/readingtoolbar"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        layout="@layout/readingbar_layout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The **FlipView** is a custom Framelayout that has a page turn animation like a book. The user is also able to pinch zoom on each page spread.

The **Toolbar** below has a selection of crayons. Once a user clicks on a color, an invisible fragment is launched and the user is able to draw on top of the page spread.

This is the toolbar Layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/readbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/defaultdark_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabtools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icontools"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabdictionary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icondictionary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tabtools"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabassessment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/iconassesment"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tabdictionary"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabexit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/iconclose"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eraser"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/drawingeraser"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guide_eraser"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crayon_black"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/drawingblack"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crayon_blue"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guide_eraser" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crayon_blue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/drawingblue"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crayon_green"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crayon_black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crayon_green"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/drawinggreen"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crayon_orange"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crayon_blue" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crayon_orange"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/drawingorange"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crayon_pink"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crayon_green" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crayon_pink"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/drawingpink"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crayon_red"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crayon_orange" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crayon_red"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/drawingred"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crayon_violet"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crayon_pink" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crayon_violet"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/drawingviolet"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crayon_white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crayon_red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crayon_white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/drawingwhite"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crayon_yellow"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crayon_violet" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crayon_yellow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/drawingyellow"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/crayon_white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guide_center"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/iconreset"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guide_center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:src="@drawable/iconshare"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tabexit2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabexit2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/iconclose"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guide_eraser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"/>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guide_center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6"/>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The toolbar initially starts out as invisible. If you click anywhere on the page, it should slide out from the bottom. I am able to capture the click event by using the dispatchTouchEvent

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

if (ev!!.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    startX = ev.x
    startY = ev.y
}
if (ev.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
    val endX = ev.x
    val endY = ev.y
    if (isAClick(startX, endX, startY, endY)) {
        onSlideViewButtonClick(reading_toolbar!!)
        return true
    } else {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    }
}
return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

So the toolbar slides out but if I click on any crayon on the toolbar, it slides back down which it isn't supposed to do. Basically, what I want is that if the user clicks anywhere else EXCEPT on the toolbar itself, then it should slide back down.

I tried using onTouch so I can pass the view instead of dispatchTouchEvent but I can't seem to capture clicks even with the same logic. I can capture a drag event, though.

```
class ReadActivity : Activity(), FlipViewAdapter.Callback, FlipView.OnFlipListener, FlipView.OnOverFlipListener, View.OnTouchListener {
...
}
```

setting

```
flip_view.setOnTouchListener(this)
```

testing the click here

```
override fun onTouch(v: View?, ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    println("clicking")
    // put actual clicking logic
    return true
}
```

Comment: Do the toolbar components have click event, or the toolbar has `android:clickable="true"` defined in xml?

Comment: Yes, it has click events but no, it doesn't have android:clickable="true". I updated the question with the toolbar layout.

Comment: So try to add `android:clickable="true"` to the toolbar to see if it consumes the touch event, moreover, you should create a new custom layout for the crayons bar, don't wrap it with `Toolbar` because I think `Toolbar` is not designed for that kind of purpose

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. Still keeps sliding up and down when clicking the toolbar itself.

Comment: Where do you define `dispatchTouchEvent`, in `Activity`?

Comment: Yes, in Activity.

Comment: So think you should catch touch event in the custom `FlipView` instead, since `Activity` will receive every touch event on every components include the `Toolbar`

Comment: Yes, actually, I think you are right and I am looking at the wrong place. I'm trying it out on the Flipview, instead.